# MessageBox returning 0 if HWND is bad

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a case where MessageBox can return 0 other than not enough memory?  I have a case where I suspect the HWND I'm passing to MessageBox isn't valid or maybe it belongs to a window that is in the process of being destroyed.

In my case the MessageBox isn't displayed and returns 0, but I seem to have enough memory available.

Comment: GetLastError helps.  It returns 1400 - ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE which makes sense.  I'm still a little confused since ::IsWindow returns TRUE on the same handle

Comment: If the window is in the process of being destroyed, then IsWindow might still technically be true even though the window is partially destroyed and therefore not useful for your purpose. Have you tried IsWindowVisible?

Comment: Both ::IsWindow and ::IsWindowVisible return TRUE before MessageBox and FALSE after MessageBox.  So, my conclusion is that MessageBox is somehow allowing the window to finish being destroyed before it is created

Comment: Yup, MessageBox is a dialog and runs a message pump.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a case where MessageBox can return 0 other than not enough memory?

From the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call  GetLastError.
```

I'd call GetLastError() to see what error code it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem go away if you pass NULL or GetDesktopWindow() as the HWND parameter? If so, then you are probably correct. You could also try to validate the HWND ahead of time with the IsWindow() or IsWindowVisible() function. (Although I'm not sure if the behaviors of those functions are reliable if the window in question is in the process of being destroyed.)